# Unable to access base class method in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base `class` as follows :

```
template<typename aGamePieceBase> class GamePiece : public aGamePieceBase
{
public:
    // Each GamePiece contains a definition of the base class from which it was derived
    typedef aGamePieceBase gamePieceBase

    // Returns this piece's sprite
    virtual sf::Sprite* getSprite()
    {
        return m_pSprite;
    }
protected:
    sf::Sprite* m_pSprite;
}
```

And a derived `class` :

```
class Horse : public GameBoard::GamePiece< GameBoard::GamePieceBase >
{
public:
    virtual sf::Sprite* getSprite() override
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
};
```

However I am presented with this error on the deceleration of `Horse::getSprite` 
Member function declared with override does not override a base class member

Why is `getSprite` unavailable in Horse?

`GamePieceBase` is as follows :

```
class GamePieceBase : public GameEventHandler
{
public:
    // Called when the GamePiece has been added to the GameBoard 
    template<typename aTileBase> virtual void onPieceCreate( Tile<aTileBase> *startingLocation ){}
    // Called when the GamePiece has been removed from the GameBoard
    virtual void onPieceRemove(){}
    // Called when the user has selected this GamePiece
    virtual void onPieceSelect(){}
    // Called when the user has de-selected this GamePiece
    virtual void onPieceDeselect(){}
    // Called when this GamePiece has moved on the board
    template<typename originTileBase, typename destinationTileBase> virtual void onPieceMove( Tile<originTileBase>* originTileBase, Tile<destinationTileBase>* pDestinationTile ){}
};
```

EDIT :
Output log is indicating there is an internal compiler `error` but does not give many details. I am investigating this now

Comment: `GameBoard` is a namespace?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes

Comment: [Unable to reproduce the error](https://ideone.com/SjFVZ7)

Comment: What's your compiler?

Comment: @user3366592 MSVC++ 14.12

Comment: Probably not significant, but `typedef aGamePieceBase gamePieceBase` - there's a lack of semicolon. Is this the actual code?

Comment: @user3366592 this was the problem in its entirety. That missed semicolon invalidated the deceleration of getSprite! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the line

```
typedef aGamePieceBase gamePieceBase
```

Forgetting a semicolon here invalidated the subsequent method deceleration and caused strange errors in the MSCV compiler output.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
class GamePieceBase
{
public:
    // Called when the GamePiece has been added to the GameBoard 
};


template<typename aGamePieceBase> class GamePiece : public aGamePieceBase
{
public:
    // Each GamePiece contains a definition of the base class from which it was derived
//  typedef aGamePieceBase gamePieceBase

    // Returns this piece's sprite
    virtual int getSprite()
    {
        return 0;
    }
protected:

};


class Horse : public GamePiece< GamePieceBase >
{
public:
    virtual int getSprite() override
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

However, it is better to write:

```
int getSprite() override
```

Writing explicit `virtual`, `override`, or `final` is self-documenting and enables the compiler to catch mismatch of types and/or names between base and derived classes. However, writing more than one of these three is both redundant and a potential source of errors. [C++ CoreGuidelines C.128](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final)